Playwright-Pytest Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop
I am able to run testcases individually using pytest and class,function fixture:
pytest test_fixtures_class.py
But when I am trying to run all classes testcases using:
pytest
I am getting following error
test_fixtures_class.py::Test_titleclass::test_portfolio - playwright._impl._errors.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.

[![Report SnapShot][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/ECAK6lZP.png

pytest test_fixtures_class.py
import pytest
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def browser(request):
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser=p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        # Attach the browser instance to the test class
        request.cls.browser=browser 
        yield browser
        browser.close()

# Define a fixture with function-level scope      
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def page(browser):
    page=browser.new_page()
    yield page
    page.close()
    
    
# Use the 'browser' fixture for the following test class
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('browser')
class Test_titleclass:
    def test_google(self,page):
        page.goto('https://google.com')
        assert 'Google' == page.title()
        
    def test_portfolio(self,page):
        page.goto('https://github-portfolio-pst99.vercel.app/')
        assert 'My Portfolio' == page.title()
        
    

Terminal Error
PS C:\Users\Desktop\playwright-python\pytest> pytest
======================================================== test session starts ========================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.12.2, pytest-8.2.2, pluggy-1.5.0
baseurl: https://www.saucedemo.com/
rootdir: C:\Users\Desktop\playwright-python\pytest
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: asyncio-0.23.7, base-url-2.1.0, html-4.1.1, metadata-3.1.1, playwright-0.5.0
asyncio: mode=Mode.STRICT
collected 9 items

test_OrangeHRM.py .                                                                                                            [ 11%]
test_demo.py ..                                                                                                                [ 33%]
test_fixtures_class.py EE                                                                                                      [ 55%]
test_fixtures_module.py EE                                                                                                     [ 77%]
test_parameter.py EE                                                                                                           [100%]

============================================================== ERRORS =============================================================== 
___________________________________________ ERROR at setup of Test_titleclass.test_google ___________________________________________ 

request = <SubRequest 'browser' for <Function test_google>>

    @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
    def browser(request):
>       with sync_playwright() as p:

test_fixtures_class.py:6:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <playwright.sync_api._context_manager.PlaywrightContextManager object at 0x000001BF7E4FFB30>

        def __enter__(self) -> SyncPlaywright:
            try:
                self._loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
            except RuntimeError:
                self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                self._own_loop = True
            if self._loop.is_running():
>               raise Error(
                    """It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
    Please use the Async API instead."""
                )
E               playwright._impl._errors.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
E               Please use the Async API instead.

..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_context_manager.py:47: Error
_________________________________________ ERROR at setup of Test_titleclass.test_portfolio __________________________________________ 

request = <SubRequest 'browser' for <Function test_google>>

    @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
    def browser(request):
>       with sync_playwright() as p:

test_fixtures_class.py:6:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <playwright.sync_api._context_manager.PlaywrightContextManager object at 0x000001BF7E4FFB30>

        def __enter__(self) -> SyncPlaywright:
            try:
                self._loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
            except RuntimeError:
                self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                self._own_loop = True
            if self._loop.is_running():
>               raise Error(
                    """It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
    Please use the Async API instead."""
                )
E               playwright._impl._errors.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
E               Please use the Async API instead.

..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_context_manager.py:47: Error
___________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_google ___________________________________________________ 

    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    def browser():
>       with sync_playwright() as p:

test_fixtures_module.py:7:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <playwright.sync_api._context_manager.PlaywrightContextManager object at 0x000001BF7E599C70>

        def __enter__(self) -> SyncPlaywright:
            try:
                self._loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
            except RuntimeError:
                self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                self._own_loop = True
            if self._loop.is_running():
>               raise Error(
                    """It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
    Please use the Async API instead."""
                )
E               playwright._impl._errors.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
E               Please use the Async API instead.

..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_context_manager.py:47: Error
_________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_portfolio __________________________________________________ 

    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    def browser():
>       with sync_playwright() as p:

test_fixtures_module.py:7:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <playwright.sync_api._context_manager.PlaywrightContextManager object at 0x000001BF7E599C70>

        def __enter__(self) -> SyncPlaywright:
            try:
                self._loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
            except RuntimeError:
                self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                self._own_loop = True
            if self._loop.is_running():
>               raise Error(
                    """It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
    Please use the Async API instead."""
                )
E               playwright._impl._errors.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
E               Please use the Async API instead.

..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_context_manager.py:47: Error
___________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_parameter[admin-admin] ___________________________________________ 

    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    def browser():
>       with sync_playwright() as p:

test_parameter.py:6:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <playwright.sync_api._context_manager.PlaywrightContextManager object at 0x000001BF7E599520>

        def __enter__(self) -> SyncPlaywright:
            try:
                self._loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
            except RuntimeError:
                self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                self._own_loop = True
            if self._loop.is_running():
>               raise Error(
                    """It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
    Please use the Async API instead."""
                )
E               playwright._impl._errors.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
E               Please use the Async API instead.

..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_context_manager.py:47: Error
____________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_parameter[test-test] ____________________________________________ 

    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    def browser():
>       with sync_playwright() as p:

test_parameter.py:6:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <playwright.sync_api._context_manager.PlaywrightContextManager object at 0x000001BF7E599520>

        def __enter__(self) -> SyncPlaywright:
            try:
                self._loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
            except RuntimeError:
                self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                self._own_loop = True
            if self._loop.is_running():
>               raise Error(
                    """It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
    Please use the Async API instead."""
                )
E               playwright._impl._errors.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
E               Please use the Async API instead.

..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_context_manager.py:47: Error
====================================================== short test summary info ====================================================== 
ERROR test_fixtures_class.py::Test_titleclass::test_google - playwright._impl._errors.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
ERROR test_fixtures_class.py::Test_titleclass::test_portfolio - playwright._impl._errors.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
ERROR test_fixtures_module.py::test_google - playwright._impl._errors.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
ERROR test_fixtures_module.py::test_portfolio - playwright._impl._errors.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
ERROR test_parameter.py::test_parameter[admin-admin] - playwright._impl._errors.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
ERROR test_parameter.py::test_parameter[test-test] - playwright._impl._errors.Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
=================================================== 3 passed, 6 errors in 11.83s ==================================================== ```


 



